# Custom compiling order in miktex

Tags: miktex, compiling, windows

I'm writing my master thesis and to get all refrences I need to run the order:

1. PdfLaTeX
2. Bibtex
3. Makeindex
4. PdfLaTeX
5. PdfLaTeX
6. (view pdf)

I'm using miktex 2.9 (64bit) on windows and these orders seems to run as .exe files. Can anyone tell me how to make this order?

Comment: there are lots of systems from a simple bat file, or latexmk or arara or rubber, plus most tex aware editors will enable you to specify such an order. But 99% of the time you just need pdflatex. You can leave the viewer running and let it update, and you only need to run bibtex or makeindex when you need to update the index or references which is far from every edit.

Answer (score 0):

I use Texworks as a front end for MikTeX (in Windows) and TeXLive (in Mac OS X). In TexWorks, the sequence of commands you need to run can be easily programmed into TeXworks (if you are capable of doing this) or you can run all these commands manually from the command bar. The sequence pdfLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX is preprogrammed, but you can choose any typesetting command you need from a dropdown box (e.g., pdfTeX, XeLaTeX, ConTeXt and so on). 
I would give TeXworks a try, it is installed with MikTeX and works very well with a big monitor, as you have two windows side by side, one with your LaTeX file and the other with the resulting pdf file.